NextJS server - execute code after starting
Is there any possibility to start nodeJs code (inside the app) when the nextJS 14 server starts (or re-starts)?
In development mode:
npm run build
npm run dev

In production mode:
node server.js

Usually a resource is missing at the time when the server starts.  There an app/api/download endpoint exists inside the code, should be called externally like
PUT http://localhost/api/download

It starts a process, which access and download the resource (translation) from some cloud provider. But the question is about - can it automatize, if the server starts, initiate this download process automatically (for the first time)?

I found something about, but still in experimental https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/optimizing/instrumentation
